# Convert data-frame to RDD[tuple] in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-migration

I have a data-frame in spark, that i wish to store in Cassandra. I dont want to use a class to `parallelize()` this and then store in Cassandra, as i want to generalize this code, to read the schema from a config file. **Now each data-frame may have a different number of columns.**

I am trying to convert a dataframe to RDD[tuple]. This is what i have tried:

```
val rddTuple = dataframe.map(r => r match {
  case r if (r.size == 3) => (r.getAs(0), r.getAs(1), r.getAs(2))
  case r  if (r.size == 4) => (r.getAs(0), r.getAs(1), r.getAs(2), r.getAs(3))
  case r if (r.size == 5) => (r.getAs(0), r.getAs(1), r.getAs(2), r.getAs(3),r.getAs(4))
  case r if (r.size == 6) => (r.getAs(0), r.getAs(1), r.getAs(2), r.getAs(3),r.getAs(4),r.getAs(5))
  case r if (r.size == 7) => (r.getAs(0), r.getAs(1), r.getAs(2), r.getAs(3), r.getAs(4), r.getAs(5), r.getAs(6))
  case r if (r.size == 8) => (r.getAs(0), r.getAs(1), r.getAs(2), r.getAs(3),r.getAs(4),r.getAs(5),r.getAs(6),r.getAs(7))
})
val cassColumn = entities.getStringList("cassandraSchemaKey").asScala //gets schema from config file
rddTuple.saveToCassandra("usermgmt", "channel", SomeColumns(cassColumn :_*))
```

This results in an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Some primary key columns are missing in RDD or have not been selected: id
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter.checkMissingPrimaryKeyColumns(DefaultRowWriter.scala:44)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter.<init>(DefaultRowWriter.scala:71)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter$$anon$2.rowWriter(DefaultRowWriter.scala:109)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter$$anon$2.rowWriter(DefaultRowWriter.scala:107)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:171)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:23)
at Main$.main(Main.scala:56)
at Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

However when i use it for a single table, it works fine:

```
val rddTuple = dataframe.map(r => (r.getAs(0), r.getAs(1), r.getAs(2), r.getAs(3), r.getAs(4), r.getAs(5)))
```

Also, is there any other way to store a data-frame to Cassandra?

Comment: Look at the type of rddTuple. When you have your match statement, every case returns a different type. So (i didn't try this) your type is probably AnyRef and saveToCassndra doesn't know what to do with it. In your working case,the map has a single type (Tuple5) and everything works.

Comment: In the working case rddTuple is of type `class org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` and in the other case its `class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD`. Why is this happening? and what is the solution?

Comment: Because tuples of different lengths are different types.  You can't just treat them as  if they are the same type. Since  any one data frame has the same number of columns, you can do `df.map(...).saveToCassandra` separately for each possible length (ie. move the `match..case` outside the `map`). That should work

Comment: Thanx, that works :)